# replace a column in a dataframe given a corresponding vector in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm looking to see if there is a quicker way to replace the days of the week in a R dataframe with a number.  Essentially, the question I'm wondering is given one vector and a corresponding vector is there a quick way to apply a replacement to a dataframe.

Here is my dataframe:

```
   month day_of_week  skies
 1   APR     Tuesday Clear 
 2   APR   Wednesday Cloudy
 3   APR    Thursday Cloudy
 4   APR      Friday Cloudy
 5   APR    Saturday Cloudy
 6   APR      Sunday Clear
```

The days of the week are in the following vector:

```
 daysweek <- unique(df$day_of_week)
 daysweek
 [1] Tuesday   Wednesday Thursday  Friday    Saturday  Sunday    Monday
```

The corresponding vector is:

```
 days_num <- c(2,3,4,5,6,7,1)
```

The long way I would do it is without the corresponding vector and using gsub individually.  I was wondering if there was a quick way to do it.  I couldn't figure it out with a for loop.

```
for (i in c(1:7)) {
  df$result <- gsub(daysweek[i], days_num[i], df$day_of_week)
}
```

Desired dataframe output I would want would be:

```
   month day_of_week  skies
 1   APR     2       Clear 
 2   APR     3       Cloudy
 3   APR     4       Cloudy
 4   APR     5       Cloudy
 5   APR     6       Cloudy
 6   APR     7       Clear
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `index` of `weekdays` and `match` with the `day_of_week` column.

```
Date <- as.Date('2014-12-29') #Monday 
Wdays <- weekdays(seq(Date, length.out=7, by= '1 day'))

df[,2] <- match(df[,2],Wdays)
df[,2] 
#[1] 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Or you can convert the column to `factor` with levels from `Monday` to `Sunday` and convert it to `numeric`

```
as.numeric(factor(df$day_of_week, levels=c("Monday", "Tuesday",
    "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday")))
#[1] 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

#### Update

If you have a `vector` of numeric indices that correspond the `unique` values in the `day_of_week` column

```
Un <- c('Tuesday',   'Wednesday', 'Thursday',  'Friday',   
        'Saturday',  'Sunday',    'Monday')
days_num <- c(2,3,4,5,6,7,1)
set.seed(24)
day_of_week <- sample(Un, 20, replace=TRUE)
unname(setNames(days_num, Un)[day_of_week])
#[1] 4 3 6 5 6 1 3 7 7 3 6 4 6 6 4 1 3 2 5 2
```

Because you used `gsub`, another option would be `mgsub` from `qdap`

```
 library(qdap)
 as.numeric(mgsub(Un, days_num, day_of_week))
 #[1] 4 3 6 5 6 1 3 7 7 3 6 4 6 6 4 1 3 2 5 2
```

or

```
library(qdapTools)
day_of_week %l% data.frame(Un, days_num)
 #[1] 4 3 6 5 6 1 3 7 7 3 6 4 6 6 4 1 3 2 5 2
```